# Dokku: App container failed to start / Could not find server ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dokku

I'm currently trying to perform the first deploy of my app with Dokku. Unfortunately, I have an error:

```
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web, webpack
-----> Releasing myapp...
-----> Deploying myapp...
-----> Checking for predeploy task
       No predeploy task found, skipping
-----> Checking for release task
       No release task found, skipping
-----> App Procfile file found
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file exists
=====> Processing deployment checks
       No CHECKS file found. Simple container checks will be performed.
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a CHECKS file. See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks (web.1)
       Waiting for 10 seconds ...
remote:  !     App container failed to start!!
=====> myapp web container output:
       Could not find server "".
       Run `bin/rails server --help` for more options.
```

I guess there's something wrong with my Procfile but I really don't see:

```
web: bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e $RAILS_ENV
webpack: NODE_ENV=production ./bin/webpack --watch --colors --progress
```

```
# dokku ps:scale myapp
-----> Scaling for myapp
proctype: qty
--------: ---
web:  1
webpack: 1
```

Any idea? Your help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was quite silly. The puma gem was in the development group, and therefore was not available in production to launch the server.